# Google login in ios with google sdk?

Tags: ios

```
@class GPPSignInButton;
```

I don't want use the `GPPSignInButton` for login and authentication i want to use my custom button when i pressed then the login process will start and the login with the Forcefully webview like facebook did it is possible in Google+ login too?
like the "[Using the OAuth 2 Controllers](https://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/wiki/Introduction#Registering_Your_Application)"
Thanks in advance

anyhelp will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use any UIButton instead  of using GPPSignInButton.

Initialise the Google+ sdk in viewDidLoad using :

```
 GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
    signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;  // Uncomment to not get the user's email

    signIn.clientID = kClientId;

    signIn.scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kGTLAuthScopePlusMe,kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin, nil];
        signIn.delegate = self;
```

Now in the uibutton action

```
- (IBAction)googlePlusSignIn:(id)sender
{
    GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    if([[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authentication])
    {
        [signIn trySilentAuthentication];
    }
    else
    {
        // This is method that opens the G+ sign view
        [signIn authenticate];
    }
}
```

Add URL type and URL scheme in Targets -> Info -> URL Types .

[image]
Then add the following in App Delegate

```
- (BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application
            openURL: (NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication: (NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation: (id)annotation {
    return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                         annotation:annotation];
}
```

Comment: [__NSDictionaryM gtm_httpArgumentsString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance " it crash with this Log message

Comment: on which line, is it crashing?

Comment: [signIn authenticate]; and one more thing is there URL type and URL scame is important to fill.

Comment: yes! you have to add that in Targets -> Info -> URL Types

Comment: for using UIWebView follow http://technogerms.com/login-with-google-using-oauth-2-0-for-ios-xcode-objective-c/

Comment: yes! just tell me the group name and I will send a request :)

Comment: ok @jenny btw my FBid is this if you want to send me a request Happy Coding https://www.facebook.com/devilNicki